# PHP class declearation

Tags: php

Actually I have idea on asp.net.In asp.net mvc we declare model,view,controller in different folders.
But I am new in PHP. So I have a question.
Is it good practice to declare both three classes model,view,controller in one .php file? 
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use a MVC structure you have to declare them in different folders. The MVC Architecture is the same in any language.

Comment: In PHP like in ASP.NET controller, model and view should be in different folders. It's good practice

Comment: @Sankalp You don't *have* to. It's actually pretty irrelevant how you split code across files or folders, as long as they *logically* form the desired separation. Having said that, it's certainly a good idea for readability and maintainability.

Comment: No. Declaring several classes in a single file is extremely stupid.

Comment: Don't know why user's give me negative vote :(

Comment: Because your question indicates complete lack of understanding about programming in general.

Comment: I only learn on asp.net mvc. I have no idea on php. That's why I ask this question. If I make a mistake asking this question then sorry to all...

Answer (score 1):

Software architecture and practices do not differ much across different programming languages. It is good software practice to have models, views and controllers each in a separate folder.